# Erro ao adicionar chave estrangeira, como proceder?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sintaxe, chave-estrangeira

Estou tentando referenciar a coluna id de uma tabela em outra tabela no meu banco de dados, mas me é informado um erro que não é muito específico. A engine sendo utilizada é InnoDB e o banco é em MySQL. Segue script gerando pelo banco e erro informado respectivamente

Sequel:

```
ALTER TABLE `service_desk_pi`.`chamado` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `estrangeiraEquipamento`
  FOREIGN KEY (`fkIdEquipamento`)
  REFERENCES `service_desk_pi`.`equipamento` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Erro:

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `service_desk_pi`.`chamado` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `estrangeiraEquipamento`
  FOREIGN KEY (`fkIdEquipamento`)
  REFERENCES `service_desk_pi`.`equipamento` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `service_desk_pi`.`chamado` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `estrangeiraEquipamento`
  FOREIGN KEY (`fkIdEquipamento`)
  REFERENCES `service_desk_pi`.`equipamento` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Aqui `REFERENCES service_desk_pi` provavelmente deveria ser o nome da sua tabela de equipamento.

Comment: Esse script com essa sintaxe é gerada pelo do próprio banco, logo após REFERENCES `service_desk_pi` tem-se . `equipamento` (`id`) que referencia o nome da tabela e também da coluna. Será que o próprio banco consegue errar na sintaxe do script que produz?

Comment: A tabela que está tentando referenciar com a chave estrangeira foi inserida com sucesso? Poderia colocar o script dela também?

Comment: A tabela já está persistida no banco. Aqui vai o script:

CREATE TABLE `equipamento` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_chamado` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  ` marca` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `modelo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `categoria` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Seria isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certeza que as engines das tabelas são iguais? Se o tipo dos campos e a engine forem iguais o código está correto.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, acabei de averiguar e vi que a tabela que seria referenciada estava em MyISAM, enquanto a tabela que faria a referencia estava em InnoDB. O erro foi de pensar que a engine se aplicava à todo o banco, ao invés das tabelas. Obrigado.